# Large initial chunk files (Empty Project with PWA and SSR) Angular 17

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering, production-environment, angular17

I am currently working on an Angular 17 project and recently generated a new empty project using Angular CLI with PWA (Progressive Web App) and SSR (Server-Side Rendering) features. However, I noticed that the size of the initial files is surprisingly large, even for an empty project.

The project starts with a standalone component, and I expected the size of the initial bundle to be relatively small. However, the initial bundle currently weighs around 214 KB.

I have verified that optimization is properly configured in the angular.json file and that I am using the ng build --configuration=production to build the project.

Is it normal to have such a large bundle size for an empty project with PWA and SSR? Are there any additional optimizations I could apply to reduce the size of the initial files?

Thank you in advance for your assistance and advice.

The app.conf.ts

```
import {ApplicationConfig, isDevMode} from '@angular/core';
import {provideRouter} from '@angular/router';

import {routes} from './app.routes';
import {provideClientHydration} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {provideServiceWorker} from '@angular/service-worker';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideServiceWorker('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: !isDevMode(),
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    })]
};
```

The main.ts

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

[Build Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaN9E.png)

adding in prod conf :

```
 "optimization": true
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Around 250kB looks to be normal size for the bare Angular project that imports the Router.

The router is [known](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42953) to have a low tree-shakability.

There isn't much to optimize here.